# Wheel covers for '95 Honda Civic EG with drum brakes

Tags: honda, brakes, civic, fuel-consumption, temperature

I have a 1995 Honda Civic hatchback with drum brakes.

I am thinking of adding wheel covers (also called moon disks). Would this affect the drum brakes  the same way it can sometimes affect disk brakes? I have read that the wheel covers can sometimes cause disk brakes to overheat.

Comment: *" I have read that the wheel covers can sometimes cause disk brakes to overheat"* - Where did you read that?

Comment: Mainly on eco/hypermiling forums. Will post links in a sec.

Comment: Not sure exactly where I read it, but it seems like there were some questions about brake heat dissipation especially during long downhills. The cars they were adding the covers to usually had disk brakes. So I am thinking that with drum brakes maybe it is not an issue.

Comment: Based on this article...
https://www.edmunds.com/car-technology/brakes-drum-vs-disc.html 
...I think drum brakes may be worse for heat build up.

Comment: That article doesn't say anything about wheel covers. It really just explains the advance to disc brakes and the advantages. Unless you are traveling at high speeds and braking under max load conditions, I doubt you would overheat your brakes, disc or drum, with wheel covers.

Answer (score 0):

No. The moon disc will block airflow from the outside of the wheelrim but airflow will still be possible from inside the wheel.

Comment: In the "good old days" when almost everything was drum brakes, wheel covers like that were common.